How to Configure an FTP Server on EC2 to Directly Upload Files to S3?
I want to configure an FTP server on my EC2 instance so that it uploads files directly to S3. This means that every file I upload through the FTP server should automatically be sent to S3. How can I set this up?
I need to upload many files that are several gigabytes in size, but I want to avoid spending money on cloud storage. That's why I am using this method.

This is not a programming question.

How is using S3 for storage not spending money on cloud storage?

Preferred method: Upload directly to S3 without using FTP (which is a 53 year-old protocol).
Alternative: Use AWS Transfer for SFTP. It will do exactly what you seek, but note that charges apply. It is a fully-manage service so you will not need an EC2 instance.

Question for you:

From where will you be trying to upload ?

If youre going to upload from a computer, then you do not need an ec2. Use AWS cli like so:

aws sts-assume-role --role-arn --role-session-name
copy the credentials to ~/.aws/credentials
aws s3 sync or aws s3 cp --recursve

If youre already uploading from ec2, then why not do :

sts-assume role
aws s3 sync or aws s3 cp ?


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I understand clearly what you're trying to achieve and here is the solution:
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/mountpoint/
Do read the "When to use Mountpoint for Amazon S3" section to make sure it fits your needs, which I believe it will.
